# Why does Google Play Store append "4" to my APK version code?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, version, phonegap

I've built an app with Phonegap/Cordova and configured its versionCode to be 16207 with attribute `android-versionCode="16207"` on `widget` tag of my Phonegap project's `config.xml`file, as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

After I run command `phonegap prepare android` it properly generates an Android project with the expected versionCode value of 16207, and then I build and sign the APK for submiting to the Google Play Store. Here is how the Android project's `AndroidManifest.xml` file looks like regarding the versionCode configuration:

[image]

The problem is, as soon as the APK is successfully uploaded to Google Play Store its versionCode is not 16207 anymore, but 162074 instead. Notice there's an "4" appended to the end of my intended configuration value for versionCode ("162074" = "16207" + "4").

[image]

I've tried to increase the versionCode value in hope that it wouldn't be changed by Google Play Store, but it always does it, and for some reason an additional "4" digit is appended to the end of whichever version code I choose for my app.

So my doubt is this: where is this additional "4" digit coming from? And how can I prevent Google Play Store from changing (e.g messing around) whith the versionCode configuration I set up for my apps? Thanks.

### Edit

I got more info about the problem. It looks like it only happens when I add more than one APK file to the same app version. When there's only one APK file the versionCode doesn't change, but when I add a second APK file Google Play appends an "4" digit to the end of the versionCode, and when I add a third APK file Google Play changes it appending a "2" digit to the end of the versionCode. I saw this because my app has three APKs: one for *Android API 23+*, another one for *Android API 16+ x86* and another one for *Android API 16+ ARMV7*.

To try to clarify a bit more, here is an schema of my APKs codeVersions and what Google Play does with them:

- **APK for Android API 23+**: versionCode 232070 doesn't change.
- **APK for Android API 16+ x86**: versionCode 16207 changes to 162074
- **APK for Android API 16+ ARMV7**: versionCode 16207 changes to 162072

You may ask why I give the same versionCode number for the last two APKs. The reason is because I know Google Play adds these strange digits to the end of their versionCodes, so in the end they won't have the same versionCode and thus this will not be a problem.

But still I would like to at least understand how and why Google Play changes the APKs versionCode instead of just using the values I give them in the config files.

Comment: I believe this is phonegaps doing while generating your APK. The play store does not modify it.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak The tool which generates my APK is Android Studio, not Phonegap. If Google Play doesn't modify the versionCode than there is some odd thing happening while Android Studio builds the signed APK. I just have no idea what it might be though.